# How to passing value multiple parameters from jquery to laravel controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have some problem with my code, I do not understand about send multiple parameters from jquery to controller

this is my route

```
Route::get('/listcdix/{id}/detail/{asnumber}', 
['as' => 'remindHelper', 'uses' => 'ListcdixController@detail']);
```

bellow is my jquery

```
otable.on("click", ".btnview",
      function () {
      var custcode = otable.rows($(this).closest("tr")).data()[0].CustCode;
      var asnumber = otable.rows($(this).closest("tr")).data()[0].ASNumber;
  window.location = "{{route('remindHelper',['id'=>"+custcode+",'asnumber'=>"+asnumber+"])}}";
          });
```

but when I click this button cannot get value `custcode` and `asnumber`

this is my URL like this

> http://127.0.0.1:3232/listcdix/+custcode+/detail/+asnumber+

please check my picture
[image]

thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.location = "{{route('remindHelper',['id'=>custcode,'asnumber'=>asnumber])}}";
```

try this one hope it works

Comment: Use of undefined constant custcode - assumed 'custcode'

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a blade directive (`{}`), so the page is expecting you will be adding a PHP segment while inside those curly braces.  You are mixing and matching between PHP and Javascript and it produces the literal `+custcode+` instead of the value behind the variable.  Same thing happens if you try to add it without removing the quotes - it translates it as a constant and will produce an 'undefined constant' error.  I.e. you are not getting down to Javascript to get to the variable.

Use one or the other, JS or PHP.  So if all Javascript, something *like*:

```
APP_URL + "/listcdix/"+ custcode +"/detail/" + asnumber;
```

Where `APP_URL` is a pre-defined variable for your url prefix.  You can cheat a little on that definition if you want and use the Laravel `url()` method to help you.  Something like:

```
var APP_URL = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!};
```

from a blade page before the JS needs to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this something like that

```
 window.location = "{{route('remindHelper',['id'=>"custcode",'asnumber'=>"asnumber"])}}";
```

because when use using curly braces {{}} in laravel. You do not need to concat this with ++. So that's why you can use this as simple format. i have checked this code on my end as well so this will be 100% work for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not combine js variable with php code as far as I know and you are using the route function and because your route needs argument to process, you need to pass variables inside the "route" function. as far as I know there is no way and you have to give the route in complete string way like this:

```
 let route = "/listcdix/" + custcode  + "/detail/" + asnumber
```